# Passing type "checkbox" is not being registered with react-final-form

Tags: react-final-form

I'm running into an issue with `react-final-form` where it tells me I'm not passing the `type=checkbox` so it cannot unpack properly. I'm a little confused because in the example the custom component does get the `type` passed to it. A live example can be found below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/9o227yp3q4

What I'm seeing is the input starts in an undefined state and is then toggled to either true or false on user input. Starting in an undefined state I think is what is causing the issue but I'm not positive.

The error message I receive is

```
Warning: You must pass `type="checkbox"` prop to your Field(attendees[0].isHost) component. Without it we don't know how to unpack your `value` prop - "undefined".
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out that I needed to pass the `type` on the `<Field />` so that `react-final-form` could unpack the values and apply them correctly.

```
export const CustomField: React.SFC<Props> = ({
  label,
  name,
  placeholder,
  type
}) => (
   <Field name={name} type={type}>
     {({ input, meta }) => (
       <div>
        <StyledLabel htmlFor={name}>{label}</StyledLabel>
        <StyledInput
          {...input}
          id={name}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          type={type}
        />
       {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
      </div>
     )}
   </Field>
```

)